# Как склеить тучу текстовых файлов?

Tags: linux

Собственно, в папке есть множество текстовых файлов с разными именами и разного размера. Надо взять и склеить и в один. Как это сделать?

Comment: @sdfds, если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку возле выбранного ответа).

Comment: Эм.. В каком порядке?

Answer (score 6):

Стандартно с помощью cat из терминала

```
cat * > summary.txt
```

Выполнять в той папке, где лежат файлы.

Comment: иногда *cat ./* > summary.txt требуется*, делает то же самое

Answer (score 1):

Иногда файлов так много, что `*` не работает. Надежней использовать xargs (см. man xargs).

Answer (score 1):

Избежать ошибки большого количества файлов:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 cat >> output_file
find /path/to/file -type f -exec cat {} \; >> output_file
```

Comment: Только вначале надо сделать `> output_file; find ...`

Comment: Можно, хотя проверил >> тоже работает сразу. Идет добавление к пустому файлу.

Comment: Существует еще -exec у find

Comment: Добавил, через xargs можно распараллелить на потоки -P ключ.

Comment: @Hellseher, если файл есть, то добавляться будет к его содержимому.